# NSStatusItem With Multiple Buttons

Tags: macos, menubar, nsmenu, nsstatusitem

Trying to get an `NSStatusItem` to have multiple buttons like this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMqgL.png.

Each button as a different function -- the pause button pauses, the skip button skips, etc. I don't want a dropdown menu, I want it all to be part of the same `NSStatusItem`.

Answer (score 4):

Add your own custom view:

```
statusItem.view = self.statusBarView;
```

Your custom view can be anything at all, including an `NSView` with several `NSButtons` inside it.

You'll probably want to create `self.statusBarView` inside a nib file.